# React + Socket.io not connecting to my server app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, heroku, socket.io

I did a lot of research but couldn't find a relevant topic yet.

I have **2 apps** that I deploy to Heroku. One in React created with "Create React App" is behaving as a client and the other is a basic Node.

When running locally everything is fine the communication between the 2 apps using socket.io is working.

**I also tested running the client app locally and connect the socket to the Node server running on Heroku and it's actually working.** But it is not working anymore when I deploy the client on Heroku

Here is how I connect the socket in the client :

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';

socket = openSocket('http://blind-spotify-backend.herokuapp.com');
```

The socket server is not the problem in my opinion :

```
let app = express()
var server = http.createServer(app)
var iop = require('socket.io').listen(server);

iop.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Un client est connecté !');
}

let port = process.env.PORT || 8888
server.listen(port)
```

I checked the heroku logs of both apps but there is no error or anything of interest. The deployement on Heroku is also going well with no warning. It's like the socket opening of the client is ignored when runned on Heroku.

What bugs me the most is the fact that this code is working when my client is runned locally and the server on Heroku.

Any idea on how I could isolate the issue would be much appreciated. I tend to think that **socket.io-client** is missing something when runned on Heroku.

EDIT : Some heroku logs of the client app :

```
2018-06-20T15:15:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-06-20T15:15:06.274695+00:00 app[api]: Release v16 created by user arondelv@gmail.com
2018-06-20T15:15:15.144186+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/boot`
2018-06-20T15:15:17.398920+00:00 app[web.1]: Injecting runtime env into /app/build/static/js/main.84449669.js (from .profile.d/inject_react_app_env.sh)
2018-06-20T15:15:17.684307+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting log redirection...
2018-06-20T15:15:17.684340+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting nginx...
2018-06-20T15:15:18.851792+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-06-20T15:16:37.285108+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.84449669.js" host=blind-spotify.herokuapp.com request_id=cb9fb26f-d63a-41a5-aa13-975229b31d38 fwd="78.194.202.199" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=89551 protocol=https
2018-06-20T15:16:37.142408+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.101.219.132 - - [20/Jun/2018:15:16:37 +0000] "GET /service-worker.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1325 "https://blind-spotify.herokuapp.com/service-worker.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"
2018-06-20T15:16:37.263979+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.101.219.132 - - [20/Jun/2018:15:16:37 +0000] "GET /index.html?_sw-precache=35fdc8fe8422c1c02fcdf50804b79478 HTTP/1.1" 200 361 "https://blind-spotify.herokuapp.com/service-worker.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"
2018-06-20T15:16:37.286746+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.235.131 - - [20/Jun/2018:15:16:37 +0000] "GET /static/js/main.84449669.js HTTP/1.1" 200 89274 "https://blind-spotify.herokuapp.com/service-worker.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"
2018-06-20T15:16:37.141096+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/service-worker.js" host=blind-spotify.herokuapp.com request_id=e45f9a70-f9a0-4048-b7cd-26e53210f03a fwd="78.194.202.199" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=1600 protocol=https
2018-06-20T15:16:37.263663+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path= "/index.html?_sw-precache=35fdc8fe8422c1c02fcdf50804b79478" host=blind-spotify.herokuapp.com request_id=8fcc33b5-03fb-4cbd-b37e-746e8d71226b fwd="78.194.202.199" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=636 protocol=https
2018-06-20T15:16:49.979987+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/service-worker.js" host=blind-spotify.herokuapp.com request_id=f8b8af4c-b66c-470c-a496-1953a517ea7f fwd="78.194.202.199" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=168 protocol=https
2018-06-20T15:16:49.979805+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.113.180.10 - - [20/Jun/2018:15:16:49 +0000] "GET /service-worker.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://blind-spotify.herokuapp.com/service-worker.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Usually this is caused by the fact that Heroku fails to bind $PORT for the create-react-app project. What are you seeing in the Heroku logs?

Comment: @brandNew I added the logs I get on client app, but I see nothing relevant in this. Do you think a port issue could prevent my client to create the socket ? Prior to the socket creation I'm doing HTTP request between the 2 apps and these are working well on Heroku

Comment: I could add a node to my client app and use the socket there without connecting to the server app. But it's frustrating not to understand the actual issue

Comment: can use please provide us what kind of output in the console of your browser please